# Oracle SQL invalid number on toad

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers

I have made this query but when I execute it, I got error about "invalid number".
But in SQL Developer for Oracle, there is no error; I got the result that I want but in Toad I got 'Invalid Number' .

```sql
DECLARE v_rep number;

BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     'SELECT to_number(REPLACE(max(substr(to_char(r_timestamp_arr,''HH24:MI''),1,2) ||
        ltrim(to_char(round(to_number(Substr(to_char(r_timestamp_arr, ''HH24:MI''),4,2)) /
        60,2),''.00''))), ''.'', '',''))  -
        to_number(REPLACE(MIN(substr(to_char(r_timestamp_arr,''HH24:MI''),1,2) ||
        ltrim(to_char(round(to_number(Substr(to_char(r_timestamp_arr, ''HH24:MI''),4,2)) / 
        60,2),''.00''))), ''.'', '','')) 
     FROM TV_MAX
     WHERE TV_UID = ''7a87e8e4861a4d0aae65da1a7248b256''' 
     INTO v_rep;
     END ;
```

Comment: NLS_DATE_FORMAT is different between session from  TOAD and SQL Developer

Comment: The problem is thaht I call this function from an API , and if It don't work on Toad it will not work on my API even if it working on SQL Developer

Comment: You probably have conversion from date to string that depends on NLS_DATE_FORMAT. I suggest checking it from session and DB parameter. Then rewritting the query

Comment: `SELECT  *  FROM    V$NLS_PARAMETERS;` and `SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT') FROM dual`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I got : 'DD-MON-RR' on Toad and 'DD/MM/RR' on Sql Dev

Comment: So first thing to check is `alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/RR';` and running your code on TOAD. Then rewritting the query to handle it correctly and being date format insensitive

Comment: Btw. I guess it should be `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` instead but try both :)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda , I have remplace all 
 NLS_TIME_FORMAT
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT 
but still the same problem.

Comment: Hi, I assume r_timestamp_arr is a column in tv_max, right?  Also, let us know what data type it is.

Comment: Why are you using execute immediate for this query? And what exactly are you trying to compute with it? doing substr(to_char(r_timestamp_arr,'hh24:mi'),1,2) is the same as to_char(r_timestamp_arr,'hh24'), and substr(to_char(r_timestamp_arr,'hh24:mi'),4,2)) is = to_char(r_timestamp_arr,'mi')

Comment: ```SELECT a FROM b WHERE x=1 INTO c``` is invalid syntax.  Its ```SELECT a INTO c FROM b WHERE x=1```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and don't need to use strings:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tv_max ( tv_uid, r_timestamp_arr ) AS
SELECT '7a87e8e4861a4d0aae65da1a7248b256', DATE '2019-12-27' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7a87e8e4861a4d0aae65da1a7248b256', DATE '2019-12-27' + INTERVAL '01:30' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If you want to ignore the date component of the date & time:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_rep NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ( MAX( r_timestamp_arr - TRUNC( r_timestamp_arr ) )
         - MIN( r_timestamp_arr - TRUNC( r_timestamp_arr ) )
         ) * 24
  INTO   v_rep
  FROM   tv_max
  WHERE  TV_UID = '7a87e8e4861a4d0aae65da1a7248b256';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_rep );
END;
/
```

**Query 2**:

If you want the min/max respecting the date component then the query can be even simpler:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_rep NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ( MAX( r_timestamp_arr ) - MIN( r_timestamp_arr ) ) * 24
  INTO   v_rep
  FROM   tv_max
  WHERE  TV_UID = '7a87e8e4861a4d0aae65da1a7248b256';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_rep );
END;
/
```

**Output**:

For the test data, both output:

> ```
> 1.5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ef77ca7510e3c7b8201f2589e84064be)*

Comment: Worked fine, great job !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like You want to know the difference between max and min hour (including minutes, excluding seconds), date part truncated. So take truncated times, subtract as dates, you will get result in days, multiply by 24, result will be in hours. Query does not depend on NLS settings:

```
select 24 * (to_date(max(to_char(r_timestamp_arr, 'hh24:mi')), 'hh24:mi') 
           - to_date(min(to_char(r_timestamp_arr, 'hh24:mi')), 'hh24:mi')) as diff
  from tv_max
  where tv_uid = '7a87e8e4861a4d0aae65da1a7248b256'
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5ac98661aeb9c001d63abbee096eae8a)</sup>**